# MYSQL select from table with duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL database.
I have a table  with four columns `id`, `sender`, `reciever` and `recieverread`;
`reciever` and `sender` columns can contain duplicate values is there a way to select only the last row with  the duplicate value?

I tried
`SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM msg WHERE sender = sender`

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your table, and some sample data

Comment: Last based on what criteria?

Comment: Your example is just selecting the `sender`?  How do you know which row it is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT sender FROM msg GROUP BY sender HAVING COUNT(sender) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent to data duplication.
You may try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM msg WHERE sender = sender group by sender
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id_last, sender, receiver, recieverread FROM msg GROUP BY sender, receiver, recieverread
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select maxid ,sender from msg where id in (
                       select max(id) as maxid from msg GROUP BY sender)
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to approach this in MySQL is with a `not exists` clause:

```
select m.*
from msg m
where not exists (select 1 from msg m2 where m2.sender = m.sender and m2.id > m.id);
```

That is, select the row for a given sender that has no larger ids in the table.